# BMW Motorrad R1150 Final Drive parts to mount R1150 brake calipers, rims and discs on R1100RS

Tags: motorcycle, bmw, drivetrain, drive-shaft

I'm working on a BMW R1100RS and have acquired the wheels & front fork of a R1150RS.
many of the parts have the same BMW catalog parts numbers.

today i removed the R1100RS rear brake caliper and tried to mount the R1150RS brake caliper.
It sits at the right spot, so basically you could use the R1150RS wheel / disc and use the old R1100RS brake caliper, it would work, but the R1150 disc has a 4.5mm smaller radius than the R1100RS brake disc that was also mounted on the K100, K1100, K1200.

the mounting lobes for the R1100RS brake caliper are equal, but the flat spot between lobes are of different length/dept and the R1150 brake caliper can't be mounted, the distance between the holes is the same, but the bracket where the caliper slides on is undeep and hits the outer Housing Cover radius

I would like to know if the: "Housing Cover Black (non)ABS - BMW-Motorrad (33112330044)" fits the final drive of the R1100RS or do i need to buy the entire final drive of the R1150RS?

Housing Cover Black ABS - BMW-Motorrad (33112330044)
https://www.shopbmwmotorcycles.com/oem-parts/bmw-motorrad-housing-cover-black-abs-33112330044?c=az0x

the Crowngear, bearings and seals are the same on the R1100RS and R1150RS

Crowngear Set - I=31:11=2.82 - BMW-Motorrad (33112330020)
[https://www.shopbmwmotorcycles.com/oem-parts/bmw-motorrad-crowngear-set-i-31-11-2-82-33112330020Ç](https://www.shopbmwmotorcycles.com/oem-parts/bmw-motorrad-crowngear-set-i-31-11-2-82-33112330020%C3%87)

Shaft Seal - 85X110X10 - BMW-Motorrad (33127663482)
https://www.shopbmwmotorcycles.com/oem-parts/bmw-motorrad-shaft-seal-85x110x10-33127663482

Grooved Ball Bearing - 85X120X18 - BMW-Motorrad (33121242211)
https://www.shopbmwmotorcycles.com/oem-parts/bmw-motorrad-grooved-ball-bearing-85x120x18-33121242211

Tapered Roller Bearing - 25X52X16.25 - BMW-Motorrad (33121450481)
https://www.shopbmwmotorcycles.com/oem-parts/bmw-motorrad-tapered-roller-bearing-25x52x16-25-33121450481

even the pivot bearing of the final drive / swingarm is the same

https://www.shopbmwmotorcycles.com/oem-parts/bmw-motorrad-needle-bearing-10x32x17-33172311091
Needle Bearing - 10X32X17 - BMW-Motorrad (33172311091)

From what i can see in YouTube video's the final drive housing and cover are made from pretty much the same casting mold, although with slight modifications between the K1100, K1200, R1100, R1150.
some casting details are present in all models.

BMW had experience with 3D printing in the 80ties, some of the famous rims we all know where made using that.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!